# How to make @mixin work without @include?

Tags: css, sass, postcss, scss-mixins

Or how can @mixin work without @include?

I have a task to understand the legacy code

**Node.tsx**

```
import IconSvg from 'ui/Icon/IconSvg'
import stylesNode from './Node.module.pcss'

// ..............
      return (
        <IconSvg
        className={stylesNode.propsIcon}
        onClick={onTextConfirm}
        />
      )
```

**Node.module.pcss**:

```
@mixin external {
  .propsIcon {
    margin: 0 -5px 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
  }
}
```

I didn't find @include anywhere in the application

The code works fine, the styles are applied, but how?

Comment: I believe your issue is that you might not be using `scss` but `postcss`. Look at the syntax for [postcss-mixins](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-mixins). Maybe you'll find `@define-mixin` in your code?

Comment: Amaury Hanser, thank you very much! 
I found @define-mixin in my code. 
the problem is not solved yet, but I approximately understood what to do. 
Thank you!